# Maven: Run Test on only one project from baseDir

Tags: java, maven

I have a multiproject maven reactor that seems to run fine when I do a general `mvn test` from `${baseDir}`, but when I run:

```
mvn test -pl myProject
```

the `${baseDir}` becomes the baseDirectory of my project rather than the top level `rootDir`. How do I run only the maven test for that single project as if it is running from the `rootDir`?

Here is the directory structure:

```
myRootProject
|-- projectA
    |-- pom.xml   // <-- this is the file that contains ${baseDir}
|--projectB
    |-- pom.xml
|-- pom.xml
```

It seems that the definition of `${baseDir}` is dependent on which `pom.xml` I run on the command line. When I use the -pl flag, `${baseDir}` becomes the directory of that project, but actually, I want it to be the rootDirectory: `myRootProject` as if I ran the root `pom.xml`.

Comment: do you have modules?

Comment: Can you write what you mean by `baseDir` with a directory tree ?

Comment: updated with directory structure and additional details. The problem is that the `-pl` flag changes the ${baseDir} to that specific project's directory. So I can't use the same project level pom.xml for `-pl` and non `-pl` calls